# Firefox bookmark icons won't show correct icon - only shows the default icon

Tags: firefox, icons, bookmarks, favicon

Whenever I bookmark a site on Firefox, the bookmark always has an icon that looks like this.

[image: picture of default Firefox bookmark icon]

How do I change it to use the icon of the page that this link is attached to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick (though slightly annoying) solution.

1. Bookmark the page that you want to bookmark

   1. It's preferable to save it on the Bookmarks Toolbar, but this solution works no matter where it's located
2. Right-click the bookmark and click `Open in New Tab`

   1. Please note that for some websites, this might be good enough to fix your incorrect icon
3. Switch tabs to go to the newly created tab (if your browser didn't do it already for you)

   1. Make sure to ***wait for the website to finish loading*** before moving on to the next step. Otherwise, you will have to start over
4. Copy the ***FULL URL*** from the address bar

   1. A suggested way of doing this is to right-click the address bar, click `Select All` from the popup, right click it again, then click `Copy` from the popup
5. Right-click the bookmark and click `Edit Bookmark...`, which will open up a new popup window
6. Find the `URL` section and paste the copied address into that section
7. Click `Save`, which should close the popup window
8. Right-click the bookmark and click `Open in New Tab`

   1. Make sure to ***wait for the website to finish loading*** before moving on to the next step. Otherwise, you may have to start over
9. Your bookmark should now have the correct icon loaded

One annoying thing to be mindful of -- if the website never had a icon to begin with, you cannot use the above method to make the icon show up! You must first be able to see the icon in your browser tab. Once you see it there, you should be able to make it work for the bookmark, as long as you copy the ***exact same url for the tab that has the icon***. That means, if you type in `youtube.com` when the tab with icon has a url of `youtube.com/`, then ***you typed in the wrong thing***. You are supposed to type in ***the exact same url for the tab that has the icon***, so in this case, it would be `youtube.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the website of the bookmark
2. Wait the page to load
3. Create a new bookmark
4. You will see the icon is there
5. Delete the old bookmark